# Drop all rows that have all NA values after last row that is not NA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
          0     1     2     3        4  
0        2.0  None  None  None  21041.0  
1        1.0  None  None  None   3003.0  
2        2.0  None  None  None   1210.0  
3        NaN  None  None  None      NaN  
4        2    None  None  None      NaN 
5        NaN  None  None  None      NaN
6        NaN  None  None  None      NaN
```

So I would drop 5 and 6 but keep 3, even though all values are NaN.

I know of:

```
df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all', inplace = True)
```

This would delete 3 as well. I guess I need to combine with some other operation.

Comment: Does this suffice : ``df.loc[:df['0'].last_valid_index()]``?

Comment: I think so. Why do you select column 0. all values need to be nan.

Comment: @BorutFlis What if there is a `non-nan` value at row with index `5` and column `4`? What will be the output in that case?

Comment: @sammywemmy this solution will not work if there are non-nan values in other columns, below the df['0'].last_valid_index()

Comment: My bad … I think @anky solution is a better option

Comment: @anky perhaps you should add it as an answer down below? Seems like a solid and nice solution indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of the last row that have at least one value not NaN and just slice the dataset until that point:

```
df=df.replace('None', np.nan)
ids = df[df.notnull().any(axis=1)].index
last_id = ids[-1]

res = df.loc[:last_id, :]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
     0   1   2   3        4
0  2.0 NaN NaN NaN  21041.0
1  1.0 NaN NaN NaN   3003.0
2  2.0 NaN NaN NaN   1210.0
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN      NaN
4  2.0 NaN NaN NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [`df.last_valid_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) + [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

Optional step in case your `None` shown here is actually text `'None'`:

```
df = df.replace(['None'], [None])   # replace text 'None' with None
```

**Main codes:**

```
df.loc[:df.last_valid_index()]
```

**Result:**

```
     0     1     2     3        4
0  2.0  None  None  None  21041.0
1  1.0  None  None  None   3003.0
2  2.0  None  None  None   1210.0
3  NaN  None  None  None      NaN
4  2.0  None  None  None      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which column is needed not NaN.so I combine column 0 and column 4

```py
df['combine'] = df['0'].notna() | df['0'].notna()
```

```
    0   4       combine
0   2.0 21041.0 True
1   1.0 3003.0  True
2   2.0 1210.0  True
3   NaN NaN     False
4   2.0 NaN     True
5   NaN NaN     False
6   NaN NaN     False
```

then I get the last True index

```py
df_temp = df[df['combine'] == True]
last_true = df_temp.iloc[-1].name
df.iloc[:last_true+1]
```

result

```
    0   4       combine
0   2.0 21041.0 True
1   1.0 3003.0  True
2   2.0 1210.0  True
3   NaN NaN     False
4   2.0 NaN     True
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just retrieve the index of the last index that does not contain only NaN values. Then use `iloc` to slice the DataFrame up to that index. You will have to add one to the found index, since you want to include this row that does not only contain NaN values.

```
df.iloc[:df.dropna(axis=0, how='all').index[-1]+1]
>>
     0   1       2       3       4
0   2.0 None    None    None    21041.0
1   1.0 None    None    None    3003.0
2   2.0 None    None    None    1210.0
3   NaN None    None    None    NaN
4   2.0 None    None    None    NaN
```

Comment: This doesn't drop 5.

Comment: I have tried this on the example df of OP and it works for me

Comment: The [current edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68141071/revisions) with 1 added to the last index works.